# how to remove form items one-by-one using jquery

Tags: jquery

is there a way wherein i can remove remove form elements one-by-one using jquery?

Here's the illustration:

[image 1](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/12081599_10153688717509726_490096964_n.jpg?oh=46a6850182f328d2c2c99eac022a238b&oe=561A4DBD&__gda__=1444505068_13b9a9bcc3d325b022e72363d82987b3)

After i have pressed "Add new required items" for several item.

i have this

[image 2](http://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t34.0-12/12080883_10153688717514726_1200930064_n.jpg?oh=b98c141643caa4bc916e431fa3c21e68&oe=561915D2)

Is there a way where in i can remove the items one-by-one using jquery?
 cause i have this code that i used

```
 $( ".remove-new-item" ).click(function() {
    $('.new-item').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `first()` and `last()` to either remove it from first or last order.

```js
$(".remove-first-new-item").click(function() {
  $('.new-item').first().remove();
});

$(".remove-last-new-item").click(function() {
  $('.new-item').last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="new-item">1</div>
<div class="new-item">2</div>

<div class="new-item">3</div>
<div class="new-item">4</div>

<button class="remove-first-new-item">Remove from first</button>
<button class="remove-last-new-item">Remove from last</button>
```

Comment: Hello He also want to add element functionality.

Comment: I see. But his requirement is only removing here. There is no need of "Add" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".add-new-item").click(function() {
  $('#items').append("<div class='new-item'> New Item </div>");
});

$(".remove-last-new-item").click(function() {
  $('.new-item').last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">
  <div class="new-item">1</div>
  <div class="new-item">2</div>

  <div class="new-item">3</div>
  <div class="new-item">4</div>
</div>
<button class="add-new-item">Add Item</button>
<button class="remove-last-new-item">Remove from last</button>
```